# How to handle circular dependencies in typedef'd structures

Tags: c, struct, circular-dependency

I have two modules, a and b.

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include "b.h"

typedef struct {
    b_t *b;
    ...
} a_t;

#endif // A_H_
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

#include "a.h"

typedef struct {
    a_t *a;
    ...
} b_t;

#endif // B_H_
```

How do I alter this so that it will compile?  (I want to keep two separate compilation units.)

---

edit: I forgot to make the structure members pointers.

Comment: I first thought, the members where pointers (what would still be questionable design, but at least possible with forward-declarations and giving at least one structure a tag)... What is this supposed to do? Both structures would require an infinite amount of memory, you can't do `struct foo { struct foo f; };` for the same reason.

Comment: A last note: Don't use `_t` as a suffix for types. Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use forward declarations:

a.h:

```
struct b_t;

typedef struct a_t {
  struct b_t *b;
} a_t;
```

b.h:

```
struct a_t;

typedef struct b_t {
  struct a_t *a;
} b_t;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it - I just had to break the cycle of typedefs by using a structure name directly.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer only applies to the original question, where pointers were not used as the struct members].

that's impossible. it's naturally not possible to have such structure.

let's say:

```
struct a {
    struct b b;
    int i;
};

struct b {
    struct a a;
    int i;
};
```

what do you expect from `sizeof(struct a)`? this struct will explode, it's impossible to compile.

however, it can be compiled if you have them turn to pointers:

```
struct a;

struct b {
    struct a *ap;
};

struct a {
    struct b *bp;
};
```

this code indeed compiles: http://ideone.com/GKdUD9.

Comment: In the original question, pointers _were_ used. He was asking about the circular dependency on the typedef.

Comment: @ColeJohnson at the beginning it was not. that's why all the answers state impossibility.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer only applies to the original question, where pointers were **not** used as the `struct` members].

You can't.

Essentially you have

```
typedef struct {
    b_t b;
} a_t;
typedef struct {
    a_t a;
} b_t;
```

and no forward declaration can help you. You have an impossible structure here: the `sizeof` would be infinite.

Comment: This “you can't” only applies to the case when the mutual inclusion is direct; it's possible when you have pointers.

Comment: In the original question, _pointers_ are used. That's not the issue.

Comment: Question has been edited: pretty much all the answers have now been invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly this isn't possible. You can't have a struct be its own member, not even transitively. This is however possible when you use a pointer. Use a structure declaration:

```
typedef struct a_struct *a_t;

typdef struct {
    a_t a;
} *b_t;

typedef struct a_struct {
    b_t b;
} a_t;
```